# Package hangs on Script Task C#

Tags: c#, ssis

Inside a For Loop container, I download a file with a script task and then with another script task I am checking the size of it. On Dev server when I execute it through SSDT, it executes with success. When I run it to the same server as a Job or adhoc execution it hangs( after downloading the 1st file). Both script tasks have try & catch and the job executes through SQL server agent. The logging shows PreExecute for the ForLoop & for the DownloadFile script task, the rest are Pre/post validations.Below the script. Any thoughts?

```
#region Namespaces
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endregion

namespace ST_7b3b944d502f476a871b7fa26cddac6e
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        public void Main()
        {
            try{
            string file = Dts.Variables["User::v_Filename"].Value.ToString();
            string Path = Dts.Variables["$Project::p_path"].Value.ToString();

            FileInfo filesize = new FileInfo(file); 
            long size = filesize.Length; 

                if (size > 100) 
                    { Dts.Variables["User::EmptyFile"].Value = false; 
                    }
                     else 
                    {
                      Dts.Variables["User::EmptyFile"].Value = true; 
                    } 
                        }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the SQL Agent job running as the same user as the one that runs it in SSDT? When you run it in SSDT is it on the SQL Server or is it on a different machine? Are you using mapped drives or UNC's? What does the code to download look like?

Answer (score 0):

In the previous script task there was a console related code. This caused the hanging of the package and it's not show as an error/warning in debugging.